# article scraping with beautifulsoup: scraping <p> tags inside <div > tags with ids

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i wrote a script in python to pull out particular paragraphs but then i end up getting all the information in that page. I want to scrap paragraphs inside  with varying ids with different pages eg.

```
<div id="content-body-123123">
```

and this id varies for different pages. How can i identify this particular tag and pull out paragraphs inside this  tag alone?

```
url='http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/op-ed/Does-Beijing-really-want-to-
ldquobreak-uprdquo-India/article16875298.ece'
page = requests.get(url)
html=page.content
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    print tag.text.encode('utf-8')+'\n'
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete and lacks enough info. Can you clarify more on what you need and what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The change of `id number` should not affect your result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/op-ed/Does-Beijing-really-want-to-ldquobreak-uprdquo-India/article16875298.ece'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
for content in soup.select("[id^='content-body-'] p"):
    print(content.text)
```